# Absolute position of element relative to page width

Tags: css, position, absolute

I don't know if I write title correctly but here is my problem...
I have DIV (`position:relative`) with few SPANs inside (`position:absolute`). SPANs are positioned for example `left:40%; top:20%` in relative to DIV. It works fine.
I want to add width to DIV - `width:200%`. As I think SPANs should aligned themselves to `left:40%; top:20%` relative to DIV which has now 200% (twice as big). And now I have problem. SPANs stays in previous position. It looks like DIV is 200% but SPANs are positioned at `left:20%; top:10%` of window width. Is this correct behavior or not? It looks like they are positioned absolute not to window size but visible area of window.
Hope you understand my post.

```
<div>
    <span style="top:40%; left:20%">Value 1</span>
    <span style="top:15%; left:15%">Value 2</span>
    <img src="img/background.jpg">
</div>
<style>
    div {width:100%; position:relative;}
    div span {display:inline-block; position:absolute;}
    img {max-width:100%}
</style>
```

Comment: you need to post your code...

Comment: seems to work for me. changing the width of the div and the top/left values of the spans moves the spans with every change https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/oewYoz